# Use multiple delimiters in golang with strings.SplitN

Tags: go

I have this line:

```
newFile := strings.SplitN(scannn.Text(), "$", 2)[1]
```

So it returns the second field after `$`, but would like to use two delimiters whatever it matches on that line, for example 2 spaces or space and dollar:    or  `$`. A delimiter can be conformed of one or more characters.

Comment: Split using [a regular expression](https://godoc.org/regexp#Regexp.Split).

Comment: @MuffinTop Could you provide the exact code replacement for that line?

Answer (score 3):

If your delimiters form a pattern you can consider using the [Split](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Split) method of `regexp` package. For the case mentioned in the question, it would mean

```
newFile := regexp.MustCompile(" [ $]").Split(scannn.Text(), 2)
```

If your delimiters are plenty in number but uni-character(rune) you can use [FieldsFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc).

Comment: Very good. Although you are missing the `[1]` at the end, otherwise says `cannot use newFile (type []string) as type string`. Do you know what's its purpose?

Comment: The return type of the `Split` method is a slice of string. `[1]` is the index of the string in returned slice, i.e., the second string of the slice.

Comment: TLDR use `newFile[1]`, but I would suggest doing a check on the length of the returned slice first.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer:

To use multiple delimiters in Go.

1.Original question: use only `$` as delimiter and get all the line text after it:

`newFile := strings.SplitN(scannn.Text(), "$", 2)[1]`

2.New question: use more than one delimiter, for example two spaces ( ) or space+dollar ( `$`):

2.1 Method one:

`` newFile := regexp.MustCompile(`  | \*`).Split(scannn.Text(), 2)[1] ``

2.2 Method two:

`newFile := regexp.MustCompile(" [ *]").Split(scannn.Text(), 2)[1]`